# How could the database executor know that "," in the SQL statement is not a split indicator?

Tags: c#, database, string

> INSERT INTO `page` VALUES (1298,0,'Ames,_Iowa','',186,0,0,0.235269435900514,'20171231234000','20171231235639',817146238,46884,'wikitext',NULL);

This is a piece of an SQL statement from the wiki dump. I am trying to turn the pieces alike into lists by splitting them with ",". However, it can be seen that there exist "," in the 'Ames,_Iowa'. I don't see any problems when directly executing the SQL statements. How does the database executor know that "," in the 'Ames,_Iowa' is not a split indicator? Is there a way for me to solve this problem?

Comment: It's surrounded by apostrophes, the DB engine knows how to parse them. You would have to do the same or find a library that does it.

Comment: Any decent parser will be able to distinguish commas between quotes from commas that are not between quotes.

Comment: Thanks!!! May you recommend some open source light-weight parser in C#?

Comment: @deathlee See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - recommendations are off-topic for the (very sensible) reasons explained in that link, and also there is google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any value between single quotes is seen as a string, which means all characters are not treated like syntax (except for some special characters like the ' sign obviously, which you can escape).

This means that you don't have to worry about your value to be split by sql server the way it is right now.

Comment: The question doesn't specify SQL Server and I think SQL Server is unlikely in this case. But your answer works for other database systems too.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that I have to turn the .sql file into .tsv file by getting out the columns in the statement but not insert the data into a real database. So I have to manually parse the statements or use some parsing tools. Are there any recommendations?

Comment: @hvd you're right. I meant to say Sql server, without the capitalization of the s in server, but I did because I work a lot with Sql Server myself. Force of habit I guess. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @deathlee I do not have any experience with `tsv` files unfortunately. If you could describe your problem without specifications like that, i.e. make your problem generic then maybe we can help. If you're really forced to parse manually, I would probably use ParseLib in Haskell because I love the language. It's really up to you how you would do the parsing.